# Expected type 'object'. Found 'void'.intelephense(1006) Issue in my project

Tags: php

I'm trying to complete the code that I'm trying to follow based on the source from youtube, but I found this error help me to solve it

this is the first part of my code section

**Database Class**

```
class DataBase
{
public $connect;
public $data;
private $sql;
protected $servername;
protected $username;
protected $password;
protected $databasename;
```

this is the second line part of my code

**construct**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->connect = null;
    $this->data = null;
    $this->sql = null;
    $dbc = new DataBaseConfig();
    $this->servername = $dbc->servername;
    $this->username = $dbc->username;
    $this->password = $dbc->password;
    $this->databasename = $dbc->databasename;
    $this->dbConnect();
}
```

this is the third line part of my code
**function**

```
    function dbConnect()
{
    $this->connect = mysqli_connect($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, $this->databasename);
    return $this->connect;
}

function prepareData($data)
{
    return mysqli_real_escape_string ($this ->connect, stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($data)));
}

function logIn($user, $username, $password)
{
    $username = $this->prepareData($username);
    $password = $this->prepareData($password);
    $this->sql = "select * from " . $user . " where username = '" . $username . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query ($this->c    onnect, $this->sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        $dbusername = $row['username'];
        $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        if ($dbusername == $username && password_verify($password, $dbpassword)) {
            $login = true;
        } else $login = false;
    } else $login = false;

    return $login;
}

function signUp($user, $fullname, $email, $username, $password)
{
    $fullname = $this->prepareData($fullname);
    $username = $this->prepareData($username);
    $password = $this->prepareData($password);
    $email = $this->prepareData($email);
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $this->sql =
        "INSERT INTO " . $user . " (fullname, username, password, email) VALUES ('" . $fullname . "','" . $username . "','" . $password . "','" . $email . "')";
    if (mysqli_query($this->connect, $this->sql)) {
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: First, run the code and verify whether it actually works. The hints shown by your Visual Studio Code extension can be useful, but they shouldn't be your primary source. Third-party extensions can miss things or even be misconfigured.

Comment: BTW, the code looks quite old and written by someone who barely knows PHP. You may want to find a better tutorial.